# Display the ArrayList values into TextVitew

Tags: android, json, arraylist

Am working on one android project. i stored the getting response in the ArrayList while parsing from the JsonArray. now i want just display the values to required text views.

Here am doing.

```
public void updateRedemptionRequestDetails(){

    //Dismiss dialog
    dlgProgress.dismiss();

    // Get the status
    String status=redemptionRequestDetailsResponse.getStatus();

    if(status.equals("success")){

        List<RedemptionRequestDetailsResource> redemptionRequestDetailsResource = redemptionRequestDetailsResponse.getData();

        if(!redemptionRequestDetailsResource.isEmpty() && redemptionRequestDetailsResource.size()==0 ){

            redemptionRequestDetailsResources.addAll(redemptionRequestDetailsResource);

            populateRedemptionDetails(redemptionRequestDetailsResources);
        }


    }else if ( status.equals("failed")) {

        //Show toast based on error code
        generalMethods.showToastMessage(context,redemptionRequestDetailsResponse.getErrorcode());

    }
}
```

Can anyone please shed some lights on this.how can i get the values in specified string and display them.

Here my model class

```
    public class RedemptionRequestDetailsResource {

    private String rdmId;

    private String rdmUniqueBatchTrackingId;

    private String rdmLoyaltyId;

    private String rdmStatus;

    private String rdmCashPaymentStatus;

    private String rdmProductCode;

    public String getRdmId() {
        return rdmId;
    }

    public void setRdmId(String rdmId) {
        this.rdmId = rdmId;
    }

    public String getRdmUniqueBatchTrackingId() {
        return rdmUniqueBatchTrackingId;
    }

    public void setRdmUniqueBatchTrackingId(String rdmUniqueBatchTrackingId) {
        this.rdmUniqueBatchTrackingId = rdmUniqueBatchTrackingId;
    }

    public String getRdmLoyaltyId() {
        return rdmLoyaltyId;
    }

    public void setRdmLoyaltyId(String rdmLoyaltyId) {
        this.rdmLoyaltyId = rdmLoyaltyId;
    }

    public String getRdmStatus() {
        return rdmStatus;
    }

    public void setRdmStatus(String rdmStatus) {
        this.rdmStatus = rdmStatus;
    }

    public String getRdmCashPaymentStatus() {
        return rdmCashPaymentStatus;
    }

    public void setRdmCashPaymentStatus(String rdmCashPaymentStatus) {
        this.rdmCashPaymentStatus = rdmCashPaymentStatus;
    }

    public String getRdmProductCode() {
        return rdmProductCode;
    }

    public void setRdmProductCode(String rdmProductCode) {
        this.rdmProductCode = rdmProductCode;
    }
}
```

here my populateRedemptionDetails method

```
 public void populateRedemptionDetails(List<RedemptionRequestDetailsResource> requestDetailsResource) {

    List<RedemptionRequestDetailsResource> redemptionRequestDetailsResource = requestDetailsResource;

    TextView txtLoyaltyId = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLoyaltyId);

    txtLoyaltyId.setText(redemptionRequestDetailsResource.getRdmLoylatyId());


}
```

i tried like this but it throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

The if condition is wrong, it will never enter:

```
if (!redemptionRequestDetailsResource.isEmpty() && redemptionRequestDetailsResource.size()==0) {
}
```

it should be:

```
 if (!redemptionRequestDetailsResource.isEmpty()) {}
```

also, small tip, when using `equals`, you should put the constant on the left side of the call, like this:

```
"success".equals(status)
```

this is to prevent `NullPointerException`s

Comment: but how can i display the values into text view

Comment: textview.setText("value")

Comment: please see my needs once again

Comment: please add the stack trace of the exception

Comment: is that way is correct to get the values from Array list.

Comment: its giving cannot resolve getRdmLoylatyId() error in this line txtLoyaltyId.setText(redemptionRequestDetailsResource.getRdmLoylatyId());

Comment: sorry man if you don't share the complete stack trace I cannot help

Comment: That is because redemptionRequestDetailsResource is a List<> according to your code. List does not have the getRdmLoylatyId method.

Comment: use redemptionRequestDetailsResource.get(0).getRdmLoylatyId()